# Qualifier doesn't work for DataSource in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have two datasources defined "datasource1" and "datasource2" (in xml configuration from a dependency).
Because of that I don't get JdbcTemplate configured by default so I need to do it manually, I do it like this:

1.

```
@Bean
public JdbcOperations jdbcOperations(DataSource datasource1) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(datasource1);
}
```

2.

```
@Bean
public JdbcOperations jdbcOperations(@Qualifier("datasource1") DataSource datasource1) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(datasource1);
}
```

In both cases it fails with:

```
Parameter 0 of method jdbcOperations in com.example.PersistentConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - datasource1: defined in class path resource [datasources.xml]
    - datasource2: defined in class path resource [datasources.xml]
```

Why the qualifier doesn't work?

I can't change the `datasources.xml` file to add a `primary=true` to `datasource`.

`datasources.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="datasource1"
          class="com.example.database.IdentifiedLazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <qualifier value="datasource1"/>
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/ak1Database"/>
                <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="identifier" value="shared"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="datasource2"
          class="com.example.database.IdentifiedLazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <qualifier value="datasource2"/>
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/ak2Database"/>
                <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="identifier" value="shared"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Do you have a typo ir really have 2 beans with name "datasource1"? According to the posted error you have 2 beans with the same name. Try to make one of them `primary`. Also try to @Autowire private DataSource datasource1; as class field rather than passing to method.

Comment: Why can't you change the `datasources.xml`?!

Comment: can you update the question with datasources.xml

Comment: @chsdk It is an external dependency (someone made a strange design decision to externalize datasources in a shared project - I can't change that)

Comment: @pvpkiran I have added the file

Comment: @StanislavL Yes, it was a typo. I can't make one of them primary (at least I don't know how to do it without changing the `datasources.xml` file, which I don't have write access)

Comment: in your xml you have dataSource1(Uppercase S) and in your Bean you have @Qualifier("datasource1")

Comment: @pvpkiran Sorry, it was a typo (I'm removing proprietary names so it is very typo-prone) In real files I've copy pasted the datasource names between files.

Comment: Hmm. Then it is really difficult to say. From the error message it looks like it is autowiring by type(instead of name and id ), which should not happen by default.  Try setting eplicit autowiring by Name using @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this wasn't working is because xml configuration *always* overrides java config (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7028).

To solve this I needed to create a bean that has *different* name then the one in the xml and mark that new bean as `@Primary`.

So now I will have three datasource beans, two connecting to the same database schema, but only one of the marked Primary so it will be used in default places instead of the xml defined one.